# JavaScript: Handle unload event on redirect

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload, onunload

Am trying to handle *unload* event on browser redirect (e.g. redirect on a button click), but it seems it is not getting triggered.
I can see *beforeunload* being triggered, but not *unload* one.

Is there a way to trigger *unload* event as well?

Comment: Do you use the "chrome" browser? If yes, the browser will not trigger the event, on browser redirect. More informations you can find here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event

Comment: Thanks @Yannick, any way to capture redirect or resource unload?